# Loading texture atlas from base64 URI Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, 2d-games, texture-atlas

I'm building a game with Phaser 3 that will be deployed and run inside a basic Chromium shell. I don't have the ability to add a server behind the scenes to handle image delivery (and prevent CORS issues), so I'm loading my assets into my game using the method described [here](https://supernapie.com/blog/loading-assets-as-data-uri-in-phaser-3).

I'm using Webpack and `url-loader` to pull in base64 encoding for my assets, and I'm loading them like this:

```
import platformSrc from './images/platform.png';
import triggerSrc from './images/trigger.png';
```

Then, I'm using the `preload()` function to add them to my texture manager.

```
preload() {
  const assetList = ['platform', 'trigger', 'audio', 'audioJson'];
  let nLoaded = 0; 

  this.cache.json.add('audioJson', audioJson);
  nLoaded++;

  this.textures.addBase64('platform', platformSrc);
  nLoaded++;
  this.textures.addBase64('trigger', triggerSrc);
  nLoaded++; 

  var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  audioCtx.decodeAudioData(toArrayBuffer(audioSrc), (buffer) => {
    this.cache.audio.add('sfx', buffer);
    nLoaded++;
    if (nLoaded >= assetList.length) {
      var actualCreate = this.createGameObjects.bind(this);
      actualCreate();
    }
  }, (e) => { 
    console.log("Error with decoding audio data"); 
    nLoaded++;  
    if (nLoaded >= assetList.length) {
      var actualCreate = this.createGameObjects.bind(this);
      actualCreate();
    }
  });
}
```

All of this works. My **issue** is trying to load an atlas using this method. I have a `atlas.png` and `atlas.json` file containing a few packed images. I created this atlas with the [Leshy SpriteSheet Tool](https://www.leshylabs.com/apps/sstool/) and exported in the `JSON-TP-Array` format.

I have tried loading my atlas like this:

```
this.load.atlas('atlas', atlasImg, atlasJson);
```

and this:

```
this.textures.addAtlas('atlas', atlasImg, atlasJson);
```

and this:

```
this.textures.addBase64('atlasImg', atlasImg);
this.json.cache.add('atlasJson', atlasJson);
this.load.atlas('atlas', 'atlasImg', 'atlasJson');
```

All to no avail. I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
>   'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the
>   signature provided.

I've been pouring over the [TextureManager](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Textures.TextureManager.html) documentation trying to figure out what I'm missing, but can't seem to put it together. Any help is greatly appreciated.